# Is there a way to test an iOS app developer account transfer?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm about to transfer an app to another developer account. Is there any way to test how it will function after transfer, before it's actually done?

Or am I missing something obvious?

I'm thinking keychain access, universal links, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no need to test it. it's explained in detail on official document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: @AmodGokhale so if it's documented you shouldn't test it?

Answer (score 0):

For the keychain part, you will loose all data stored on keychain. Also you should use different keys after transfer.

For the universal links, just change the team id stored in apple-app-site-association file and you will be all good.